Regex: Find all matches between varying length sets of identical special characters
I have texts similar to this:
<FILE_NAME>
���������������
</FILE_NAME>

<SHEET_NAMES>
['������']
</SHEET_NAMES>

<RAW_STRINGS>
[������������]

Where any length of the special character � serves as a placeholder. I'm trying to use regex to get a list of all the strings before/between/after the special characters. So in this example the output should be:
["<FILE_NAME>\n", "\n</FILE_NAME>\n\n<SHEET_NAMES>\n['", "']\n</SHEET_NAMES>\n\n<RAW_STRINGS>\n[", "]"]

The best I got so far is this:
�+(.+(?!�))�+

I tried to match as many as possible of �, then capture everything except �, then again �. Doesn't return any results.
This is unfortunately not as simple as finding text between two delimeters. The delimiters in both ends here are the same, and can be of varying lengths, so any method I tried tends to match the delimiter itself in between sets of delimiters.
For example using this:
(?<=�)(.*?)(?=�)

just matches the first � and the second one.
